# Writing data from a sensor to a file

Tags: python, sensors

I am trying to write data from a sensor to a .txt file in a loop that takes the readings every 30 seconds, but currently its not taking readings from the sensor (or its not writing them to the right place)

I have a `while(True)` loop as:

```
f = open('/home/pi/sensor_data.txt','a')
while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    data = humidity, temperature
    textdata = str(data)
    f.write('textdata\n')
    time.sleep(30)

f.close()
```

this wants to take readings from the sensor every 30 seconds and write it to the file sensor_data. Currently its only writing 'textdata' to the file, how do I go about writing actual data from the sensor to it? I am very new to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f.write(textdata+'\n')
```

will get your job done

When you use

> f.write('textdata\n')

, Then it will treat "textdata" as a string just like "anmol" and not as variable name so the value is not substituted, However , removing it outside the "...." will get you desired results.

Answer (score 0):

`f.write('a')` will write `a` in your text file. Here, `textdata` is a variable name. Since you want to write the contents of the the variable, use

```
f.write(textdata+'\n')
```

instead of `f.write('textdata\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `print` function instead of `f.write('textdata\n')`:

```
print(humidity, temperature, file=f)
```

If you use Python 2 then add at the top of the module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and replace all `print` statements with corresponding function calls.